# Android Skip Bluetooth Dialog

Tags: android, bluetooth, dialog, skip

I'm sending with a raspberry pi over bluetooth some files to the smartphone and show some stuff on the display.
The transfer working over Obex Object Push - but thats the problem.
(And new protocol isn't a solution for now).

Always if the raspberry sending a file, I have to accept the filetransfer on my phone.
Is there any way to skip the request or to make some auto accept in the background?

Comment: did you got any solution for this problem? I have the same problem with any device with ICS or greater...